# I can't make the document have the proper paper size

Tags: texmaker, paper-size, dvips

I'm using the MikTex 2.9 distribution on Windows 7 and the Texmaker editor. I'm using the sequence Latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf to produce my pdf file but it always come out with the A4 paper size and nothing I have tried changes it to a letter size document.

I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[paperheight=11in, paperwidth=8.5in]{geometry}
```

and

```
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \pdfpaperheight=11in
  \pdfpaperwidth=8.5in
\else
  \special{papersize=11in,8.5in}
\fi
```

I have also tried the MikTex settings but change the paper size default to letter accomplished nothing.

When I use the PdfLatex everything works fine but because I had some problems between PdfLatex and some packages I have to use I got to get the right paper size with the Latex->dvips->ps2pdf sequence. Any ideas what could be done? Because the PdfLatex works I believe the problem is with the dvips bit but I don't know if this is correct and if it is I don't know how to configure it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Check this posting ex.stackexchange.com/questions/96489/miktex-default-papersize-setting.  This may be a duplicate.

Comment: `geometry` will pick up the class option and you don't need to tell it the size of US letter paper. Are the DVI and/or PS the correct size? They should be if you have class option `letterpaper` and just say `\usepackage{geometry}`. However `geometry` is somewhat buggy, in my experience.

Comment: How do I check the physical size of a .dvi and/or .ps file?

Comment: I think that `dvi2ps` is changing the paper size. You can try to convert using command line and pass the paper size option just to confirm if it works. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/dvi2ps.1.html

Comment: Where do I insert this command line? Do I change the config.ps file on the dvips folder?

Answer (score 1):

Copy this After of

```
\begin{document}

\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
```

Great Solution